# Get stuck with use of "take + noun"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

> A sample mix bar mixes the sample and the reagent. **The photometer continues to take readings.**

Form the above message, what if I would say "the photometer continues to **take reads**"? As read can also act as a noun, one of its parts of speech, so it still has exactly the same meaning?

Anyway, the meaning what I mean is the photometer is still collecting data - optical density - from the reaction mixture several times rather than the photometer is still reading. Well, in my opinion, there must be something described to tell in more particular unless it just says "The photometer **continues to read**"

I'm not quite sure of what I thought is right? Anyone give me some suggestions please

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as it stands is correct: "The photometer continues to take readings." "Reads" is not the noun form of the verb "to read," "reading(s)" is the noun form.